# React Three OrbitControls breaks on state Change

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I made an application with react, react-three/fiber and react-three/ drei. I'm trying to change a state while orbiting around. Unfortunately as soon as I change any state while orbiting around my OrbitControls is no longer working, except zooming out via scroll wheel works as expected.

I was able to recreate my issue in a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/807t0y

If you comment out line 17 in my controls.js file you can drag rotate and zoom. Otherwise you can only zoom out with your mouse wheel.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in regard